# How to covert Innodb table to myisam tables in minimum downtime

Tags: mysql

we have 250GB mysql innodb databases,  for performance reason we have to convert it in myisam on production, so  what will be the optimal solution to do it in minimum downtime

Comment: What interface do you use to access your databases? I don't know but I would guess you copy your tables; and adjust the copies and then delete the originals and renam the copies. Although to be honest I'd just update the tables directly, but then I don't know your system

Comment: What performance reason?

Comment: these are reporting database so  we are converting all innodb table to myisam to speed up selection

Answer (score 0):

I'd imagine something like:

- Create MyISAM copy of table.
- Add/modify triggers on original table to "sync" changes to copy.
- Incrementally copy old data from original table to copy; update and delete triggers should keep previously copied data up to date. *(Depending on specific table's structure and how you are incrementally copying, an insert trigger may be unnecessary or even counter productive).*
- Drop any foreign keys referencing original table.
- Rename original table and rename copy to original table's name.

It won't be the fastest process, but I can't see having less downtime than renaming a couple tables.